# How to export a VirtualBox appliance to a NAS?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, nas, export, smb

I'm using VirtualBox 3.1.2 (r56127) on Linux (Ubuntu 9.10 64-bit).

I'm trying to use **Export Appliance** utility to clone my virtual machines over local network using [SMB](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/smb) protocol to [NAS](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nas). I decided to do it because some machines are larger than free space on my local disk drive - lack of space for the clones.

Simply, I specify [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) path in the folder selection dialog box, for example:

```
/home/mloskot/.gvfs/mloskot on browarekhd/VirtualBox/clones
```

The process starts but after a minute or so the [VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) throws an error. Here is screenshot with the exact error:

[image]

How should I understand it?

- Does it mean export over network is not supported?
- Does it mean there is a bug in VirtualBox?
- Or, simply I must not have used GVFS path as the one above as it consists of spaces in `mloskot on browarekhd` ?

Please, share your experiences on this matter.

p.s. I asked very similar question on VirtualBox forum: [Export Appliance over network to NAS](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=27374) I hope it's nothing against the SU rules :-)

UPDATE: Maciek suggested below to copy `vmdk` file to NAS manually. Generally, it would work, but as I specify in my question, I can't generate `vmdk` file (by exporting VM locally first) on my box where I keep all my VMs due to lack of disk space.

UPDATE2: Eventually, I managed to free some disk space and followed Maciek's suggestion, thus marking it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to copy vmdk file to NAS manually. Then import it to virtual disk manager, and crate new vm using it.